# Lua decompress gzip from string

Tags: string, nginx, lua, gzip, compression

I have some trouble with decompress gzip from string in lua. (mb bad understanding)

Response of one web-services is base64-encoded gzip string, for sample I get some code on C#.

```
    public static string Decompress(byte[] value, Encoding Encoding = null)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;
        Encoding = Encoding ?? System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
        using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream(value)) 
        using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())                              
        {
            using (var zip = new GZipStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))  
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
                int n;
                while ((n = zip.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    outputStream.Write(bytes, 0, n);
                }
                zip.Close();
            }
            return Encoding.GetString(outputStream.ToArray());    
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string encodedText = "H4sIAAAAAAAEAHMNCvIPUlRwzS0oqVQoLinKzEtXyC9SyCvNyYFxM/OAqKC0RKEgsSgxN7UktQgAwOaxgjUAAAA=";

        byte[] decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedText);

        var decodedString = Decompress(decodedBytes, Encoding.UTF8);

        Console.WriteLine(decodedString);

    }
```

I try to do this with lua (on nginx) and make from base64 string array of byte

```
local byte_table={};
base64.base64_decode(res_string):gsub(".", function(c){
 table.insert(byte_table, string.byte(c))
})
```

but have some problem with [zlib](https://luapower.com/zlib).

Please help me understanding how can I use IO stream in lua and decompress gzip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I try to do this with lua (on nginx) and make from base64 string array of byte

No, you are making Lua table with bunch of numbers.

Decode base64 and feed to zlib the whole resulting string.

I'm use http://luaforge.net/projects/lzlib/ for gzip decompressing:
`local result = zlib.decompress(str,31)`

Comment: Googled it somewhere.

Comment: `local result = zlib.decompress(base64.base64_decode('H4sIAAAAAAAEAHMNCvIPUlRwzS0oqVQoLinKzEtXyC9SyCvNyYFxM/OAqKC0RKEgsSgxN7UktQgAwOaxgjUAAAA='),31);`

ERROR! Empty string or null string in input parameter